# How to import method from one package to another for the directory structure below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-packaging

Below is the directory structure where I am having trouble importing modules.

```sh
.
├── A
│   └── a.py
└── B
    └── C
        └── b.py
```

Let's say, there's a method `foo()` in `B/C/b.py` which is to be imported into `A/a.py`.

However, when I try importing `foo()` as shown below -

```py
# A/a.py
from B.C import foo
```

I get an error saying -

```sh
unable to import 'B.C'.
```

An alternative way that I tried was using **relative imports** like this -

```py
# A/a.py
from ..B.C import foo
```

But again, I get an error saying

```sh
Attempted relative import beyond top-level package.
```

How exactly should I import `foo()` from `B/C/b.py` into `A/a.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure your project as a **package**.

By adding `__init__.py` file as specified [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html#packages), you are specifying a top-level package, therefore you will be able to import B/C/b.py with the command:

```py
from src.B.C import b
```

```
src
├── __init__.py
├── A
│   ├── a.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── B
    ├── __init__.py
    └── C
        ├── __init__.py
        └── b.py
```